# 500 server error building wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am writing a plugin that creates categories based on an amount specified by a form. So I have the form page, it works, you can access it from the dashboard menu. When the form is posted it sends to a php page with this code on it:

```
//includes this file so that I can use wordpress functions
include '../../../wp-includes/pluggable.php';
//comes from the amount specified by the form
$assignmentamout = $_POST['assignmentamout'];
//comes from what to call the categories input part of the form
$namethem = $_POST['namethem'];

//if the input box for naming the assignments is blank, this is the default
if($namethem == "") $namethem = 'Assignment';

//repeat the createcat categories function for as many times as stated in the form
for ($i = 1; $i <= $assignmentamout; $i++) {
    $create = $namethem." ".$i;
    createcat($create);
}
//run this function as many time as the loop says
function createcat($created){
    wp_insert_term($created, 'category');
}
```

If I click 'submit' on the form. I immediately get a server error: "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

I tried putting the wp_insert_terms() directly into the loop and tried using wp_create_category(). If I do not include the pluggable.php I get a 'function not found' php error. I ran a lot of echos so I know that the script just stops at the wp_insert_terms(). I tried to look up server errors, but my server didn't log any errors. I increased my memory in my php5.ini to 20mb. All my files in my plugin and its folder are permission 755. Plugin's that I have installed from elsewhere are working properly. If I remove the wp function I get no server error, the page outputs echos I put at the end.

Maybe I am just building this plugin incorrectly. Any help that anyone could give me would be much appreciated! Or maybe suggest how you would build this part of a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked up my server logs to see what the problem was. Looks like I needed to include the taxonomy.php not the pluggable.php. I had to include a lot of different wordpress pages by the end of this plugin. And you can find what php page each function is called from in the wordpress documentation at the bottom of the page of the function you are reading about. I guess moral of the story is: a 500 error = look at your server logs! AAAHHHH noobs...